# Is there a way to prevent refresh on mouse click of a browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have prevented Browser back button by clearing history and possible key events for refreshing the page but the only thing I need is to prevent mouse click on refresh button of the browser. Can anybody help me out here?

```
history.pushState("", "");
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    history.pushState("", "");
});
$(function() {
    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 116: //F5 button
                event.returnValue = false;
                event.keyCode = 0;
                return false;
            case 82: //R button
                if (event.ctrlKey) {
                    event.returnValue = false;
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    return false;
                }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If I happen to land on a site that does that, I don't think I'd ever come back.

Comment: Have you also though of preventing the opening of the js console? You can't and you should not prevent those actions. If you need this, you've got a bigger problem, somewhere else on your page.

Comment: Ps : the why you need this is obviously the what you should fix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already have customized back button in all my pages, So I don't have to worry coming back!

Comment: What you are trying to do is to make the browser bug. Even if what you asked was possible (it's not) users won't understand why their native back button doesn't work. You've got customized back button, well, why do you want to disable the native ones ? Your code won't block mac users. Your code won't prevent anyone to enter in their console `location.href=''`or `location.reload()`. Your code won't prevent users to open a new window and load it again. Your code will just make users like me and @Shikkediel never come back to your website, it won't prevent us to do what we want with our browser.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `window.onbeforeunload` event handler. In your page, use a hidden field, to control, when leaving (refresh - is a leaving and entering again) your page is legitimate.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        var isPageUnloadAllowed = true;

        // check legitimacy of page unload, and return false, if it is prohibited, if it is allowed, return true 


        return isPageUnloadAllowed;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can't prevent the default behaviour of beforeUnload, you can just provide a prompt asking the user if he really does want to leave.